# UV map lost when export to FBX

Tags: texturing, uv, .fbx

With Blender 4.0 on a Windows 11 PC.

I did UV maps on my model.

[image]

But when I export this model in FBX (and import it in another software or another blender fiel), UV maps and shaders are brocken/lost on multi-shaders parts.
Not on single shader part (hair).

[image]

How can I fix this?
Should I split the multi-shader part into several?

Thank you in advance.